# How to Build NextJS Project on Local without Now

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-scripts, next.js

I need to build **My React NextJS Project** on local to host it **at Appache server**, when I run command `run build` it did not generate build folder.

I R & D on it, everyone recommend `ZEIT – Next.js build with Now` but it build project on cloud but I need a build for my local appache server. So please help me out.

Here is an my of package.json:

```
......
"scripts": {
"dev": "node server.js",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start"
},
......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After so many struggle, I found answer of my question I have to add following line in my package.json under scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    ......
    "export": "npm run build && next export"
    .....
},
```

Basically I my case, `npm run build && next export` was complete required command to build NextJS project. So after adding this into package.json you just need to run in terminal: 
`npm export`
 and it will generate complete build for nextjs project.

Comment: This only works if your app isn't creating any dynamic pages at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You have a package.json script called `build` that runs `next build`. The `next build` command by default builds the app for development, which doesn't create a production bundle.

In order to create the production bundle on your local machine, you need to specify that you're on production environment through `NODE_ENV=production` (this is done automatically in now and other deployment servers). Basically, your package.json would end up:

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "node server.js",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"prod:build": "NODE_ENV=production npm run build"
},
```

You can replace `npm run build` with `next build` directly if you prefer that.

Comment: Does not create a build folder on next v7.0.2 for me. Do you know another method?